# Can I set a workspace specific alias, rc, or another dotfile for the Integrated Terminal in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code

I've looked at the [Terminal Profiles documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles) but it looks like you can only set args here, not any commands to run like `source $cwd/.vscode/.customrc` or `alias foo='foo cmd'`. Any ideas? Trying to achieve specific aliases that only make sense for a single development environment/workspace.

Comment: You can define a variable, which identifies your workspace, and in your startup file test the variable and according to this, setup your workspace-specific configuration.

Comment: Were you able to find a way to get this working? This is a useful feature / technique for me, too.